# can't link a controller to a customized class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/50310/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-2), and I am trying to link a class to a controller, the tutorial says the following:

> Add a new file to the project and name it PlayerDetailsViewController, subclass of UITableViewController. To hook this new class up to the storyboard, switch back to Main.storyboard and select the new Table View Controller scene (the one that says “Root View Controller”). In the Identity inspector set its Class to PlayerDetailsViewController. I always forget this very important step, so to make sure you don’t, I’ll keep pointing it out.

I followed the steps in the tutorial, and I created the class that is called "PlayerDetailsViewController" but as shown in image-1 below, in the "Custom class" section in Xcode, the name of my class is not listed and when I added manually and press Enter, later it disappears

please let me know why that is happening and how to fix it

**image-1**:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select `Root View Controller` instead of `tableView` and then try to change the class.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select yellow color Root ViewController Controller if it **TableViewController** . and then assign **PlayerDetailsViewController** to there .

You can't assign `UIViewController` subclass to `UIView(tableview)`.

If you want assign subclass of UITableViewController then you need to drag TableViewController to storyboard then you will able to assign this class.